# How to stop an start Juju instances on Amazon EC2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm testing a Hadoop cluster with juju and Amazon EC2, and I would like to know how could I stop a cluster and then start it again, manteining the cluster configuration. 
The problem is that after start the instances again the public addresses changes, and the juju-status command shows the machines are down.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that after start the instances again the public addresses changes

Above is true for EC2 instance. Its Public IP address changes when it is stopped and then started.
To avoid this, you have 2 options:

1. use Elastic IP. You can attach an EIP to you instance so that the instance will have the same IP address accross the start/stop cycles. **Caveat:** you can get only 5 EIPs per account.
2. To get rid of above limitation of 5 EIPs per account, you can setup your cluster in side a VPC where all your instances will have a private IP address and it will remain same across start/stop cycles. But you have to understand how VPC works in order to use that. Please read [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenarios.html).